# Phantom &nbsp; Showing up in my page

Tags: html

I have a page written in HTML/ASP that has a series of nested tables that I use for formatting the page the way I want it.

When the page loads however there is a white space between the two tables that is not in the code and when I inspect it in chrome it shows the code has a `&nbsp` character between them.

Why is this appearing in the page when it loads but it is not in the script? How can I remove it?

```js
<table width=100% border=2 cellpadding=0>
<tr>
  <table width=100%>
    <tr>
      <th width=10% align="right">Destination:</th>
      <td width=60%>Here</td>
      <td width=10% align="right">Date:</td>
      <td width=20% align="left">&nbsp;<%=FormatDateTime(d,2)%></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</tr>
<tr>
  <table width = 100%>
    <tr>
      <td width=2%>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="right">Time1:</td>
      <td align="center"><%=formatTime(oRS1("time"))%></td>
      <td><%=oRS1("location")%></td>
      <td width=40>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="right">Driver</td>
      <td>&nbsp;<%=fpn%></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you should make sure there is no whitespace between the elements in your script

Comment: I did, I even went as far as deleteing ALL the whitespace in the editor. Just had "<TAG><TAG><TAG><TAG><TAG>....". The phantom `&nbsp;` is still there.

Comment: Next suggestion would be send all of your html print data to the console. ie `console.log(html)` and see what it is printing. It could also be the browser itself adjust for an abnormality in the HTML

Comment: You have posted ASP code. What does the resulting HTML look like? If `&nbsp;` is in the ASP code, then you seem to have an issue with the authoring tool you are using. Some tools are known to convert normal spaces to `&nbsp;`, usually for no good reason.

Comment: I am using Notepad++ to edit my code if that is what you mean by an authoring tool. I am not familiar with console.log(html), how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue and here are the steps that I tried that eventually fixed it:

1. Cleared the cache in the browser
2. Cleared all browser data
3. Tried a different browser

None of the above worked in my case, and the phantom `&nbsp;` was not in my code (and I triple checked it!!!!), but it was obviously somewhere since it was showing in the console and other browsers:

[image: Circled nbsp in console]

So, (and this may not be the best way to solve this but it worked) as you can see from my console output, I added two paragraph tags above and two below (by carefully putting the cursor in front of the next element and using a carriage return and the arrow key to go back up) to get the phantom `&nbsp;` in the middle. After that I saved it, then proceeded to select and delete the two paragraph tags in the middle together (with the phantom `&nbsp;` between them). This is what finally worked, the delete of both the elements surrounding it together took the phantom `&nbsp;` with it...

Perhaps some small part of my html page became corrupted? Who knows... but if anyone else is having this issue, give this a try.